# Multiple labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

I have followed tutorial for labelling from multiple columns, e.g. name and also grade. Looks correct in expression but nothing shows in output preview.  Any idea where I am going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please add more detail (where did you put this expression, did it work with a single column, what are your label setting....)

Comment: Better look in the final map ... i think the preview is usually based on a given row (first one ?) and is eventually empty ... at least syntax looks ok ...

Comment: Hi, yes works with single column, eg "Name" and it shows up in preview.

Comment: Doesn't show any labels on final map

Comment: what specific label settings info do you require?

Comment: You might also try the function concat as an alternative: concat ("Name", '\n', "Grade"). If it doesn't work: try skipping '\n' - does it work with just "Name" and "Grade"? If you use singe colum "Grade", then what is your output?

Comment: Maybe a **type conversion** issue when you concatenate the strings ... ? How is the content of **"Grade"** structured ?

Comment: Have you tried another option than new line (\n)? E.g. "Name" || '-' || "Grade" just to make sure that the whole label-string is shown and no parts of it hidden due to lack of space when covering two lines. And are you sure both attributes are strings?

Comment: Have solved the issue, upon checking the attribute table there was a null value in grade.  Doh!  Have added value and now shows both name and grade.  Not all entities have a grade so those that don't do not show at all (even the name) but those have a grade now show both name and grade.  Thanks everyone, got there.

Comment: However, the expression should work, even if some entries have NULL-value. To this respect, I guess that the concat-function works better than using the pipes || - in my test-example, when I used pipes, then all entities containing a NULL-value were not labeled at all (as in your case), whereas using concat, the label showed just those information that was available. So it seems to be better to use concat.

Comment: Hurrah, concat works.  Thank you so much. I have learnt loads.